# SharePoint 2013 get list item field value

Tags: javascript, list, sharepoint, field, sharepoint-2013

I have a document library where I added a text column `Read`. I'm using a script editor web part to insert some JavaScript. I need to get the value of this column `Read` for a specific item (I know the item Id).

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code worked:

```
this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemid);
ctx.load(this.oListItem);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, 
    function () {prevText = this.oListItem.get_item('Read'); }),  
    function (sender, args) { alert('Error occured' + args.get_message());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Sharepoint client object model to get the document library where you added the text column. After that you can get the list item by building a caml query with the item id and you can get the value of your column.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) or [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) to help you. With SharepointPlus the code would be:

```
$SP().list("Name of your list").get({fields:"Read",where:"ID = 123"}, function(data) {
  if (data.length===1) alert("Read = "+data[0].getAttribute("Read"))
  else alert("Unable to find ID 123")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [SPServices](http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/) and [jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js), you can reference those in your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>
```

Then get the fields of the current item using this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Don't forget to replace the document library's name
        // if it's not "Documents"...
        getListItems('Documents',
            function(items){
                var e = items.getEnumerator();
                while (e.moveNext()) {
                    var item = e.get_current();
                    //console.log(item.get_item('FileLeafRef'));  //print File or Folder Name
                    //console.log(item.get_item('FileRef')); //print File or Folder Url
                    var read = item.get_item('Read');
                    alert('Read = ' + read);
                 }                
             },
             function(sender,args){
                 console.log(args.get_message());
             }
        );
    });

    function getListItems(listTitle,success,error)
    {
        //alert('getting items');
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
        var items = list.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());
        context.load(items);
        context.executeQueryAsync(
           function() {
               success(items);
           },  
           error
        );
    }
</script>
```